# AWS: Is there a way to make an user approve my app to do things on their behalf?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am planning on a web page that creates an instance for an user using a specific AMI. Is there any AWS method to let the user approve my web application to do this using their credentials? (i. e. getting a secret token with certain privileges)

Similar to when you let a Facebook application have access to certain information of your profile. I am looking for a way to get a token from the user signed in so that I can create an instance for them.

I want to avoid the user the pain of doing all the manual steps of going to IAM, create a new user, get the token and then upload them to my site.

I looked into AWS Cognito but this doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Similar to when you let a Facebook application have access to certain information of your profile.

AWS and Facebook are not similar in any sense.  Facebook is a web application.  AWS something entirely different.

Facebook has users, but AWS has *accounts*, which in turn have users... but in AWS, don't need a *user's* permission to do things to resources -- what you actually need is an *account's* permission to do things to *its* resources, because resources are associated with the account, not the user.

> I am looking for a way to get a token from the user signed in so that I can create an instance for them.

Users sign in to the AWS console.  After this, there is no such concept as a user allowing an external application doing things under the "signed in" user's auspices.

The user has to have sufficient permissions to either create sufficiently-privileged temporary IAM credentials (such as with GetSessionToken or AssumeRole from the IAM API) and hand them over to you, or create an IAM user with sufficient privilege and hand the keys to that user over to you... or you provide them with the ARN of one of *your* IAM users, and your customer gives your user permission to perform the actions or assume a role in your customer's account, created for the purpose.

> I want to avoid the user the pain of doing all the manual steps of going to IAM, create a new user, get the token and then upload them to my site.

That can't be avoided, by design... and, in any event, whatever exactly you are planning, your model seems flawed: it would only be a naïve user who would allow you to do this.  I have accounts that are allowed to launch hundreds of instances concurrently.  Does it make sense that I would allow a third party to have access to credentials that could run up a huge bill for me?  (If AWS trusts a set of credentials to launch instances, then it trusts them to launch instances -- all the way up to the account's instance limits).

If you want a user to be able to launch an instance from your AMI, you can simply list it on the [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/), or you can [share the AMI with the user's account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html), or even just [make the AMI public](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-intro.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am targeting home users who doesn't have an account with another services running. I will have to look into AWS Marketplace or something like that.